# IntersectionObserver not firing on inital load - can it be done manually?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have three elements which I want to run individual functions for when they scroll fully into view.

I have achieved the desired behaviour using `IntersectionObserver` as in code below, but there's a problem. If I reload, I need to scroll to trigger the events. I think this is possibly happening becuase the `.observe` methods are being called inside a function which runs after `DOMContentLoaded` fires.

Is there any way to manually trigger `scrolledIntoFrame` to check intersections?

```
const scrolledIntoFrame = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
                scrolledIntoFrameFunctionMap[entries[0].target.id]();
            }
        }, {threshold: [1]});

        //TODO trigger events if on load item in view
        scrolledIntoFrame.observe(document.querySelector("#statRowed"));
        scrolledIntoFrame.observe(document.querySelector("#statRaised"));
        scrolledIntoFrame.observe(document.querySelector("#map"));
```

Answer (score -5):

Yes it can, try coding it on repl.it, if it's not working, then there's the problem is not in the code and it is on your computer/laptop and if it's not working, try running it on another platform/website or computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).